# How can be set -theoretically defined the whole collection of possible circles in a given plane P ? ( not using analytic geometry)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, euclidean-geometry

[ edited 9th april 2019]

I'd like to solve this question using only basic concepts of geometry ( without analytic geometry) and of elementary set theory.

If I am correct, the following process allows me to " build" the desired set. But, how could I express, in a single formula,the result of this process,  using  the proper logical and set theoretical symbolism?

(1) I choose an arbitrary point O (as first "center").

(2) I define an equivalence relation : the set (of points) A is equivalent to the set (of points) B iff all the elements of A are at the same distance from O as are all the elements of B ; I obtain an infinity of equivalence classes ( one for each possible " orbit")

(3) inside each equivalence class ( that is , for each " orbit") I choose the greatest set using the inclusion relation ( for the circle is the greatest set amongst sets whose points are all at a given distance from a given "center"); I obtain an infinity of circles for the first center O.

(4) I repeat (1)-(3) for each point  in the plane, that is, for each possible "center".

(5) Using, maybe, the union operation, I gather all my ( infinite) collections of circles for a given center in a new set , which would be the set of circles in a  plane P.

Remark - This is not homework; it is a question I ask myself, as a gratuitous exercise in logic/ elementary set theory

Comment: Pay attention to the difference between a set and its points. The set CIRCLE you defined is a set of subsets. The union of all subset is all the plane (every point is contained in some circle) but the set CIRCLE is not the plane

Comment: Why not $C=\{(x,y,r): r\gt 0\}$?

Comment: @ John Douma -  Is a triple sufficient? Would we need a quadruple in order to take the center into account ? Or not?

Comment: @Eleonore Saint James - I think (x,y) is the centre.

Comment: I think I understand in which way a given circle can be identified by a triple < x, y, r> x and y being the coordinates of the center and r the radius. But I am wandering whether this triple is " able" to define the circle as a set of points. Is it the case?

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames If you mean circles in the plane then a triple is sufficient. If you mean circles in space then you need more than a quadruple because you need the same triple as well as a description of the plane. Since you need a vector and a point to define a plane you would need $6$ additional points. Actually, you can do it with seven real numbers in 3D. Can you see how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematicians already have a symbol for a circle of radius $r$ centred at $(x_0 ,y_0 )$, it is $$B((x_0 ,y_0 ),r)=\{ (x,y) | (x-x_0 )^2 + (y - y_0 )^2 = r \}$$  Then, the set of all circles is $$C=\{B((x_0 ,y_0 ),r) | r>0, (x_0 ,y_0 ) \in Plane \}$$

Comment: @ NazimJ - Thanks for your answer. ( I upvoted). I think this answer is correct. Do you think it would be possible to define the desired collection without using analytic geometry?

Comment: You could let $\vec{x}$ denote a point on the plane, then as mentioned in previous comments, every open ball $B(\vec{x}, r)$ can be "labelled" by an ordered pair $(\vec{x},r)$. And the set $\{(\vec{x},r) |r>0 \}$ is isomorphic to the set of all circles, since every circle has a label, and every label corresponds to a circle (it is a bijection).  Is that what you are looking for?